# Example of convex function with global min that is Lipschitz but does not have Lipschitz gradients

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, lipschitz-functions, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

In gradient descent, when optimizing a convex function with a global minimum, one often assumes either that

1. the function is Lipschitz, or
2. that its gradients are Lipschitz.

There are [examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3681813/339790) where 2 does not imply 1. Are there any examples where 1 does not imply 2 (restricted to convex case with a global min)?

Comment: How about $f(x) = |x|$?

Comment: Thanks. What about cases where 1 does not imply gradients are a.e. Lipschitz?

Comment: Also where the function is differentiable everywhere.

Comment: As to your first question: $f$ being Lipschitz *never* implies that $\nabla f$ is Lipschitz.  As to the second question, consider $f(x) = |x|^\alpha$ with $1 < \alpha < 2$. Then $f'(x) = \alpha  x|x|^{\alpha - 2}$. This is not a Lipschitz function.

Comment: Thanks, nice example. You are right, I should have worded better: where 1 holds but 2 does not.